# Wordpress admin admin change button text add new

Tags: wordpress, backoffice

I'm looking for change button text "add new" in wordpress pages list and post list.

- For pages list I would like the button text become : "add new page"
- For posts list I would like the button text become : "add new post"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by putting below code in your theme's functions.php file

```
function change_post_object_label() {
        global $wp_post_types;
        $post_labels = &$wp_post_types['post']->labels;
        $page_labels = &$wp_post_types['page']->labels;

        $post_labels->add_new = 'add new post';
        $page_labels->add_new = 'add new page';

    }
    add_action( 'init', 'change_post_object_label' );
```